# Java Collection: what to convert Collection<List<String>> to ArrayList<List<String>> or List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections

I am using `Multimap<String, List<String>>` in one of my API's. Now to get all the values means list of list I used the `.values()` method of the multimap. But this method is returning me `Collection<List<String>>`. Now to play on the index on this collection I want to convert it into `List<List<String>>` or `ArrayList<List<String>>`.

How to cast or convert without building new arrayList and explicit add list values from collections to that arraylist.

Comment: Why would you need to convert the `Collection<Whatever>` into `List<Whatever>` in the first place? What's the benefit from this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you chose MultiMap? It looks like you are not using it correctly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza As i mentioned I want to play on Index value. I have two such list and I want to iterate time parallelly that's why I need to play on index. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: @JNL: i used the MultiMap because in my business use case I need to have values against duplicate keys thats y...

Comment: Even using the *index*, you can use a `Pair<String, String>` instead and store the strings in the *same index*. Also, you can achieve the same behavior using `Iterator<String>` from the collection instead of blindly trusting on `List#get(int index)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the appropriate constructor:

```
List<List<String>> yourList = new ArrayList<>(yourCollection);
```

The order of the elements in the list is the order of the iterator of the collection.

Comment: While this address the problem stated by OP, I wonder the real benefit/improvement to convert the `Collection` into a `List`.

Comment: OP wants to "_play on the index on this collection_", that's why I added info about the order of the elements. But, yes: it would be helpful to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: That looks like a design problem. I think we're facing [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I thought that when I saw `Multimap<String, List<String>>` ... A `Multimap` maps a key to multiple values, why was a `List` chosen as value type...

Comment: Well, we can only hope OP reads these comments and explains the real problem to get better help instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to build a new collection (and don't forget, that may not be costly since you'll create the new collection but not clone the actual members), why not just do

```
int i = 0;
for (List<String> list : collection) {
   // whatever
   i++;
}
```

Not hugely nice, I appreciate.

Comment: I guess you meant `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: I did indeed. Thx. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Or use google collection API

```
List<List<String>> = Lists.newArrayList(myMap.values());
```